# angularjs htttp post не доходит до сервера

Tags: angularjs, express

помогите разобраться с проблемой, post запрос не доходит до сервера и висит в ожидании. Использую стек angularjs+expressjs

post запрос на клиенте:

```
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/message',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: {msg: $scope.message}      
        }).

        success(function(response) {
            console.log("Success " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }).

        error(function(response) {
            console.log("Error " + JSON.stringify(response));
        });
```

сервер:

```
app.post('/api/message', function(req,res) {
    var message = new Message(req.body);
    message.save();

    res.status(200);
})
```

вот такое сообщение получаю в консоли:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/api/message
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown  
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/?
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
view source
{msg: "231313"}
  msg:"231313"
```

Comment: Попробуйте вывести на сервере в консоль `req.body`,  и откройте проект в другом браузере.

Comment: на сервере в консоли сообщение "231313" отображается, но все так же висит статус pending, из-за этого в бд сообщение не записывается, не понятно что не так сделал..

Comment: Получается запрос доходит до сервера. Может проблема с сохранением в БД? Не записывайте в БД, а просто верните браузеру статус 200, либо это же сообщение.

Comment: app.post('/api/message', function(req,res) {
    var message = new Message(req.body);
    message.save();

    res.status(200);
})

вот тут я и как раз возвращаю статус 200, но тогда почему он не записывает в бд, когда тот же req.body выводится в консоли..

п.с. с бд работаю через mongoose

Comment: Вместо  `res.status(200)` попробуйте `res.status(200).send()`, это точно отправит ответ браузеру. Почему не сохраняет? Нужно добавить функцию внутрь метода `save(function...)`,  лучше посмотрите в документации.

Comment: запрос доходит, внутри метода добавил функцию, теперь ругается на promise, просит подключить библиотеку, хотя в базу сохраняется и без функции внутри метода, просто почему то не записывается само сообщение, в базе пустой объект с id. может я неправильно передаю данные в контроллере?

Comment: Как я понял текущий вопрос решен, добавьте ответом что Вам помогло.  По поводу промисов, чем ругается нода и не сохраняет объекты в БД - это уже другой вопрос, оформите его как отдельный и изложите его подробнее.

Comment: прописал res.status(200).send() как вы указали, это решило проблему с post запросом, спасибо))